# Why does this ptrace program say syscall returned -38?

Tags: c, linux, ptrace

It's the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462230/why-wifsignaledstatus-fail-to-detect-signals-while-tracing-a-process-with-ptrac) except that I'm running `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);`.

The result is obviously wrong as every syscall returns with `-38`:

```
[user@ test]# ./test_trace 
syscall 59 called with rdi(0), rsi(0), rdx(0)
syscall 12 returned with -38
syscall 12 called with rdi(0), rsi(0), rdx(140737288485480)
syscall 9 returned with -38
syscall 9 called with rdi(0), rsi(4096), rdx(3)
syscall 9 returned with -38
syscall 9 called with rdi(0), rsi(4096), rdx(3)
syscall 21 returned with -38
syscall 21 called with rdi(233257948048), rsi(4), rdx(233257828696)
...
```

Anyone knows the reason?

**UPDATE**

Now the problem is :

```
execve called with rdi(4203214), rsi(140733315680464), rdx(140733315681192)
execve returned with 0
execve returned with 0
...
```

`execve` returned `0` **twice**,why?

Comment: Where is the source for test trace?

Comment: Likely same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503425/in-linux-on-entry-of-a-sys-call-what-is-the-value-in-eax-not-orig-eax , but this is better because it has code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The code doesn't account for the notification of the `exec` from the child, and so ends up handling syscall entry as syscall exit, and syscall exit as syscall entry.  That's why you see "`syscall 12 returned`" *before* "`syscall 12 called`", etc. (`-38` is `ENOSYS` which is put into RAX as a default return value by the kernel's syscall entry code.)

As the [`ptrace(2)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) states:

> PTRACE_TRACEME
>
> > Indicates that this process is to be traced by its parent. Any signal (except SIGKILL) delivered to this process will cause it to stop and its parent to be notified via wait(). **Also, all subsequent calls to exec() by this process will cause a SIGTRAP to be sent to it**, giving the parent a chance to gain control before the new program begins execution. [...]

You said that the original code you were running was "the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462230/why-wifsignaledstatus-fail-to-detect-signals-while-tracing-a-process-with-ptrac) except that I'm running `execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);`".  Well, it clearly isn't, because you're working with x86_64 rather than 32-bit and have changed the messages at least.

But, assuming you didn't change too much else, the *first* time the `wait()` wakes up the parent, it's not for syscall entry or exit - the parent hasn't executed `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...)` yet.  Instead, you're seeing this notification that the child has performed an `exec` (on x86_64, syscall 59 is `execve`).

The code incorrectly interprets that as syscall entry.  *Then* it calls `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...)`, and the next time the parent is woken it *is* for a syscall entry (syscall 12), but the code reports it as syscall exit.

Note that in this original case, you never see the `execve` syscall entry/exit - only the additional notification - because the parent does not execute `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...)` until after it happens.

If you *do* arrange the code so that the `execve` syscall entry/exit are caught, you will see the new behaviour that you observe.  The parent will be woken *three* times: once for `execve` syscall entry (due to use of `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...)`, once for `execve` syscall exit (also due to use of `ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL,...)`, and a third time for the `exec` notification (which happens anyway).

---

Here is a complete example (for x86 or x86_64) which takes care to show the behaviour of the `exec` itself by stopping the child first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>

#ifdef __x86_64__
#define SC_NUMBER  (8 * ORIG_RAX)
#define SC_RETCODE (8 * RAX)
#else
#define SC_NUMBER  (4 * ORIG_EAX)
#define SC_RETCODE (4 * EAX)
#endif

static void child(void)
{
    /* Request tracing by parent: */
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);

    /* Stop before doing anything, giving parent a chance to catch the exec: */
    kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);

    /* Now exec: */
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);
}

static void parent(pid_t child_pid)
{
    int status;
    long sc_number, sc_retcode;

    while (1)
    {
        /* Wait for child status to change: */
        wait(&status);

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
            printf("Child exit with status %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
            exit(0);
        }
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("Child exit due to signal %d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
            exit(0);
        }
        if (!WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            printf("wait() returned unhandled status 0x%x\n", status);
            exit(0);
        }
        if (WSTOPSIG(status) == SIGTRAP) {
            /* Note that there are *three* reasons why the child might stop
             * with SIGTRAP:
             *  1) syscall entry
             *  2) syscall exit
             *  3) child calls exec
             */
            sc_number = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child_pid, SC_NUMBER, NULL);
            sc_retcode = ptrace(PTRACE_PEEKUSER, child_pid, SC_RETCODE, NULL);
            printf("SIGTRAP: syscall %ld, rc = %ld\n", sc_number, sc_retcode);
        } else {
            printf("Child stopped due to signal %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        }
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Resume child, requesting that it stops again on syscall enter/exit
         * (in addition to any other reason why it might stop):
         */
        ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, child_pid, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
        child();
    else
        parent(pid);

    return 0;
}
```

which gives something like this (this is for 64-bit - system call numbers are different for 32-bit; in particular `execve` is 11, rather than 59):

```
Child stopped due to signal 19
SIGTRAP: syscall 59, rc = -38
SIGTRAP: syscall 59, rc = 0
SIGTRAP: syscall 59, rc = 0
SIGTRAP: syscall 63, rc = -38
SIGTRAP: syscall 63, rc = 0
SIGTRAP: syscall 12, rc = -38
SIGTRAP: syscall 12, rc = 5324800
...
```

Signal 19 is the explicit `SIGSTOP`; the child stops *three* times for the `execve` as just described above; then twice (entry and exit) for other system calls.

If you're really interesting in all the gory details of `ptrace()`, the best documentation I'm aware of is the
[`README-linux-ptrace`](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/doc/README-linux-ptrace) file in the [`strace`](https://github.com/strace/strace/) source.  As it says, the "API is complex and has subtle quirks"....

Comment: Now the problem is that `execve` returned `0` **twice**,why?

Comment: @new_perl: The `execve` syscall happens once.  The child stops three times while tracing that one syscall happening (once for entry, once for exit, once as a notification that an `exec` has happened).  Those are the three `syscall 59` lines in the above example.

Comment: Isn't the value `-38` in `eax` enough to distinguish between syscall entry / exit? (ptrace man page states "Syscall-enter-stop and syscall-exit-stop are indistinguishable from each other by the tracer.")

Answer (score 0):

You can print a human-readable description of the last system error with perror or strerror. This error description will help you substantially more.

Answer (score 0):

At a punt I'd say you're examining `eax`, or its 64 bit equivalent (presumably `rax`) for the return code of a system call. There's an additional slot for saving this register named `orig_eax`, used for restarting system calls.

I poked around into this stuff quite a lot but can't for the life of me locate my findings. Here are some related questions:

- [In Linux, on entry of a sys call, what is the value in %eax? (not orig_eax)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5503425/in-linux-on-entry-of-a-sys-call-what-is-the-value-in-eax-not-orig-eax/5505693#5505693)
- [Why is orig_eax provided in addition to eax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6468896/149482)

### Update0

Poking around again it seems my memory serves correct. You'll find everything you need right [here in the kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L585) (the main site is down, fortunately torvalds now mirrors linux at github).