# Ptrace catching many traps for execve

Tags: c, system-calls, ptrace

I am using ptrace to intercept system calls. Everything seems to be working fine except for the fact I'm intercepting 16 calls to execve (8 for pre system call, and 8 post system call).

I have seen working examples without it, but I'm trying to use the flag `PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD`.

Other [answers to ptrace problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514837/why-does-this-ptrace-program-say-syscall-returned-38) indicate I should only see one pre/post + one signal, but they're not using `PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD`.

My output looks like:

```
Intercepted rt_sigprocmask[14]
Syscall returned with value 0
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value -2
Intercepted execve[59]
Syscall returned with value 0
Tracer: Received signal: 5
Intercepted brk[12]
...
```

The rest of the output matches what `strace` outputs.

Every "Intercepted" and "Syscall returned" corresponds to one `waitid()` call. A minimalist example code to reproduce this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/user.h>
#include <sys/vfs.h>
#include <sys/ptrace.h>
#include <sys/reg.h>     /* For constants ORIG_EAX, etc */
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>    /* For SYS_write, etc */
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  pid_t pid = fork();

  // Child.
  if(pid == 0){
    ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Wait for parent to be ready.
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    execlp("pwd", "pwd", NULL);
    return 0;
  }
  // Tracer.
  else{
    struct user_regs_struct regs;
    bool isPre = true;
    int status;
    // Wait for child to stop itself.
    waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, NULL, PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD);

    while(true){
      ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0);
      pid  = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

      // Check if tracee has exited.
      if (WIFEXITED(status)){
    return 0;
      }

      // This is a stop caused by a system call exit-pre/exit-post.
      if(WIFSTOPPED(status) && WSTOPSIG(status) == (SIGTRAP |0x80) ){
        ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, NULL, &regs);

        if(isPre){
          printf("Intercepted syscall: %llu\n", regs.orig_rax);
          isPre = ! isPre;
        }else{
          printf("Done with system call!\n");
          isPre = ! isPre;
        }
      }else{
        printf("Tracer: Received signal: %d\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
      }
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I fear I'm misundersting `execve`, or `PTRACE_O_TRACESYSGOOD`.
I'm running this on Lubuntu 16.04 with kernel version 4.10.0-37-generic.

edit: Fixed return values for system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing's wrong. One call to `execlp` will typically result in multiple calls to `execve`, each of them (except for the last) returning `ENOENT` as the error code.

Despite the fact that `execlp` and `execvp` are often documented in section 2 (system calls) of the Unix and Linux manuals, they're implemented as userland functions. They look through `$PATH` and call `execve` on the concatenation of each `$PATH` component and the executable name, until either one execve succeeds or they all fail.

Here's some of the source from [musl](https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/process/execvp.c) that illustrates what's going on:

```
if (strchr(file, '/'))
    return execve(file, argv, envp);

if (!path) path = "/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin";
...
for(p=path; ; p=z) {
    char b[l+k+1];
    z = strchr(p, ':');
    if (!z) z = p+strlen(p);
    if (z-p >= l) {
        if (!*z++) break;
        continue;
    }
    memcpy(b, p, z-p);
    b[z-p] = '/';
    memcpy(b+(z-p)+(z>p), file, k+1);
    execve(b, argv, envp);
    if (errno == EACCES) seen_eacces = 1;
    else if (errno != ENOENT) return -1;
    if (!*z++) break;
}
if (seen_eacces) errno = EACCES;
return -1;
```

Comment: Perfect this is just what I was looking for! Since tools like `strace` only show a single call to execve I thought I had an error.